# Orb Alternative for playing media on-the-go with mobile devices

Tags: streaming, media, dlna

I have a collection of legitimate media files (movies, songs, etc) which I have purchased over the years. I used to use Orb (www.orb.com), which would catalog all of the media files on my server, and provide a Flash-based interface so I could then stream my multimedia files to mobile devices, phones, etc, over the internet and watch them while I'm traveling.

Are there any alternatives (preferably open-source) that I can use in place of Orb. I do not trust the company itself, and do not like the idea of having an account with a list of all my media collections stored online. Being a veteran techie and programmer, I prefer to set up my own firewall rules, server configurations, etc, and not have to rely on any sort of credentials being handled by a third party. The only person who should even know of the existence of this server is myself, not some company making money by harvesting data on my and the files on my computer.

The one thing I really liked was the Flash interface, since, between that interface and the others provided, I could play on any device (ie: Playbook, laptop, mobile phone, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ampache](http://ampache.org/) is open source, with a repo on [Gitorious](http://gitorious.org/ampache).

> Ampache is a web based audio/video streaming application and file manager allowing you to access your music & videos from anywhere, using almost any internet enabled device.